# div doesn't resize height enough

Tags: html, css, height

When the content of my #pageContent div goes beyond the screen, the div doesn't resize itself as I would expect, even if I add a "clearing" div at the end of the data.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="pageContent">
  ... stuff here
  </div>  
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

scroll down here on the example:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0mxzy9w9/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `height: 100%` to `min-height: 100%`...

```
#pageContent{
    padding:30px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background:#fff;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0mxzy9w9/2/)

`height: 100%` will restrict the height to the height of `body`. `min-height` will allow your element to expand beyond if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to set height (or min-height) on the html element.

```
html {
    /* height: 100%; */
}    
#pageContent {
  ...
  overflow: hidden; /* or auto, or whatever */
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0mxzy9w9/4)**

Also, this is what's causing the horizontal scroll. It's not necessary, either.

```
body {
    width:100%;
}
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0mxzy9w9/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

add `#pageContent height: auto;`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body{    
    background:#0000ff;
}  

#wrapper{
 width:90%;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 position:relative;
 max-width:1400px;
 background:#fff;
 height:100%;
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
}

#pageContent{
 padding:30px;
 height: auto;
 background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="pageContent">
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        
            
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Use below css for your div tag

```
div {
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this :

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0mxzy9w9/7/)

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0%;
}

body{
    background:#0000ff;
    overflow:auto;
}

#wrapper{
    width:90%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    max-width:1400px;
    background:#fff;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
}

#pageContent{
    padding:30px;
    height:100%;
    background:#fff;
}
```